# Physics2D.OverlapBox() не работает. Что делать?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я пишу скрипт передвижения в юнити 2д, и решил вместо Physics2D.OverlapCircle() использовать Physics2D.OverlapBox(), но он не работает.

Gizmos отрисовывает всё правильно, слой проверил, считывается только одна точка в центре квадрата.

вот аргументы:

(feetPos.position(позиция у ног персонажа), checkFieldSize(размеры квадрата), 0(без понятия для чего это), whatIsGround(слой земли))

что я делаю не так?

Comment: Третий аргумент -- это угол поворота квадрата. А что не работает? Что значит `считывается только одна точка`? Может размеры квадрата отличаются от Gizmos? Можете показать ваш код?

Comment: Вместо всего площади квадрата считывается только точка в его центре. В Gizmos.DrawCube указаны такие же параметры как и в  Physics2D.OverlapBox().к сожалению, по некоторым причинам нет.